# Firebase Android Auth Error

Tags: android, firebase-authentication

I am building a firebase android app which enables sign in functionality. The problem occurs after running the code. I get the following message in logcat:

```
W/ResourceType: Found multiple library tables, ignoring...
W/DynamiteModule: Local module descriptor class for com.google.firebase.auth not found.
```

Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: which version of firebase library you are using ?

Comment: version 1.0.1 @PriyankPatel

Comment: VersioN 10.0 is available .whatever u r using is deprecated.https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup

Comment: @RishabhMaurya, I have the dependencies up to date but auth error message still persists.

Comment: Post your `build.gradle`, please.

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:10.0.1'
```

in your gradle file.

if that does not work, try inserting

```
FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
Log.d(TAG, user.getEmail());
```

these lines in your

```
@Override
public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {}
```

So you can get a idea about if the authentication happens or not properly

If you can post your code, that will be helpful to solve the problem easily

Answer (score 0):

1)Log into your firebase console and Enable Email/Password Sign-In_Method, it should solve the issue.

2)Try re sync your client with your Firebase app, and add again the .json file. In android studio 2.3 just click on tools>firebase and in the assistant check if your app is connected to.
3)use this in build.gradle implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.6.0'